# Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs', cannot find module 'webpack-cli'

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-cli

I have tried nearly all solutions however nothing has worked for me. i cloned a repo from a friend and tried to run the client directory. When i try run client, i get the error:

- Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
- Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'

Once i cloned the project i did `npm install` (as it said in the readME) but when i tried to run the client i would run into this problem:

solutions i tried:

- `npm install -g vue-cli`
- `npm install --save-dev webpack`
- `npm install --save-dev webpack-cli`
- i tried '`webpack --version`' it will tell me i am missing something and if i want to install it. i click yes and i get the following error:

Installing 'webpack-cli' (running 'npm install -D webpack-cli')...
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.1 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@3.4.0 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@3.1.11 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-cli@3.3.11 requires a peer of webpack@4.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- webpack-cli@3.3.11
  updated 1 package and audited 12959 packages in 13.437s

24 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 33 vulnerabilities (22 low, 7 moderate, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
My colleague updated some of the dependencies by GitHub bot and i pulled the repo. That seemed to do the trick